# Magento 2 WYSIWYG in repeater field

Tags: magento2, backend, wysiwyg, custom-field, array

I am trying to make a (very simplified) page builder for just the homepage in Magento 2.3.

I figured out how to build a repeating field from a serialized array, like this :

```
            <field id="footer_links_2" translate="label comment tooltip" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Footer links (Midden)</label>
                <frontend_model>Brancom\FooterContext\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Footerlinks</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
            </field>
```

This is the model

```
    class Footerlinks extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * @var Factory
     */
    protected $_elementFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Factory $elementFactory
     * @param array   $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Factory $elementFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_elementFactory = $elementFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addColumn('name', ['label' => __('Tekst')]);
        $this->addColumn('link', ['label' => __('Link')]);
        $this->_addAfter       = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Voeg Toe');
        parent::_construct();
    }

}
```

But I can't seem to find a way to add a column with a WYSIWYG field.
Is this even possible?